# Where can I get a terrarium?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I've picked up a few pets in Kingdom of Loathing, and there's not really anything I can do with them except a button saying to put them in a terrarium.  When I try it, it helpfully tells me I have no terrarium.

Where can I get a terrarium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy one at the **General Store** in the **Market Square**.

Comment: Hi there, please don't use backticks for emphasis as per [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful). Bold/italics are intended for this. Thanks!